How to show only 1 product variation in product view rather than all variations?
I've setup a simple website with many products, some of which have multiple variations.
I've got a view of products which is showing all variations of every product. I just want to show 1 of each variation.
I can't find a contextual filter or filter which would achieve this.

To display only one variation for each product in your Drupal view, you can use aggregation to group the product variations together and then display just one from each group. Here's how to achieve it:

Enable Aggregation in the View:
Edit your view. Under the Advanced section in the view editor, find the Use aggregation option and enable it.

Group the Variations by Product: Add a field that uniquely identifies the product (e.g., Product ID or a reference field pointing to the product entity).
When aggregation is enabled, the view will allow you to group rows based on this field.

Set Up Aggregation for the Fields: For each field in your view, configure its aggregation settings. Click the gear icon next to the field and choose an aggregation function. For instance, you could use "COUNT", "GROUP BY", or "FIRST" depending on what makes sense for your data.

Add a Distinct Filter (if Necessary): If your variations are differentiated by a field (e.g., SKU, color), you can add a filter to select only one variation per product. For example, if you want to show the first variation, sort by a field (like SKU) and limit the result to the first row per group.

Sort the Data: Define the sorting order so that the variation you want to display appears at the top of each group (e.g., sort by a date field or SKU).

Test and Save: Preview the view to ensure only one variation per product is displayed. Save the view.


